# Different ways of Starting a MapReduce Job

Tags: hadoop, java-8, mapreduce, bigdata

What is the difference between starting a map reduce job in Apache Hadoop using simply the job.waitForCompletion(true) method and via ToolRunner.run(new MyClass(), args)?

I have a MapReduce job executed in following two ways:

First as follows:

```
public class MaxTemperature extends Configured implements Tool {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperature(), args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
  }

  @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
              System.exit(-1);
            }
        System.out.println("Starting job");
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
        job.setJobName("Max temperature");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

        if(job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was successful");
        } else if(!job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was not successful");           
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And second as:

```
public class MaxTemperature{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
              System.exit(-1);
            }
        System.out.println("Starting job");
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
        job.setJobName("Max temperature");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

        if(job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was successful");
        } else if(!job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was not successful");   

    }
}
```

The output from both the ways is same. But I'm not getting what is the difference between the two?
Which one is more preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post does a pretty decent job of explaining the use of ToolRunner : [ToolRunner](https://hadoopavenue.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/tool-toolrunner-simplifying-the-concept/)

Comment: please, avoid link-only answers. instead, try to provide the basics of the answer here and then provide the link for more details. If the link gets invalid, so will your answer

Comment: @vefthym you are right. The link isn't working. I have the same question as the author of this question. can someone please explain. Thanks!